# How to see name inside the link after renaming by jQuery?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, foreach

Jsp loop:

```
<c:forEach items="${feedList}" var="feed">
    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" id="feedId"
        value="<c:out value="${feed.id}" />" />
    <tr>
        <td class="feed-name" id="<c:out value="${feed.id}" />"><c:out
                value="${feed.name}" /></td>
        <td><a
            href="FeedController?action=delete&id=<c:out value="${feed.id}"/>">Delete</a>
        </td>
        <td><a
            href="FeedItemController?action=feedItemListAsc&id=<c:out value="${feed.id}"/>">View</a></td>
        <td><button
                onclick="openEditDialog('${feed.id}', '${feed.name}' )" name="modal">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I want to make feed.name inside View button like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${feedList}" var="feed">
    <input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" id="feedId"
        value="<c:out value="${feed.id}" />" />
    <tr>
        <td class="feed-name" id="<c:out value="${feed.id}" />"><a
            href="FeedItemController?action=feedItemListAsc&id=<c:out value="${feed.id}"/>"><c:out
                    value="${feed.name}" /></a></td>
        <td><a
            href="FeedController?action=delete&id=<c:out value="${feed.id}"/>">Delete</a>
        </td>

        <td><button
                onclick="openEditDialog('${feed.id}', '${feed.name}' )" name="modal">Edit</button></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

But my jQuery edir button after renaming `$('.feed-name[id="' + id + '"]').text(name);` removes link. It becomes visible as link after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over-writing all the content in your target selector `.feed-name` when you use `.text()`

If you want to target the link, you'll need to do something like this:

```
$('.feed-name[id="' + id + '"] > a').text(name)
```